# ReportValidity Shows Only On Last Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have a boostrap4 modal and click save button in modal will do validation checking on server. After checking, if there is errors, return errors and using setCustomValidity on every input/select with error. Lastly, use reportValidity to show all invalid popup message.

The problem is: The popup only shows for the last input/select of the errors, instead of showing for all.

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server" novalidate>
    <table>...
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">...</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contacts" class="col-form-label">Contacts:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contacts" name="contacts">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" onserverclick="ValidationCheck">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</asp:Content>
```

```js
function saveAlert({data = {}}) {

    let invalidateInputs = [];
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        $("#modal").modal("show");
    },700);

    Object.entries(data.UserInfo).forEach((detail) => {
       ..repopulate modal with data
    });

    Object.entries(data.Errors).forEach((error) => {
        switch(error[0].toLowerCase()) {
            case "name":
                if (error[1] == false) {
                    invalidateInputs .push(document.querySelector("#name"));
                
    document.querySelector("#name").setCustomValidity("Please fill in your name");
               }
                break;
            case "contacts":
                if (error[1] == false) {
                    invalidateInputs .push(document.querySelector("#contacts"));
          
  document.querySelector("#contacts").setCustomValidity("Please fill in your contacts.");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    if (invalidateInputs.length > 0) {

        // (*) even though this loops all input, the popup showed up only at last input
        invalidateInputs.forEach((input) => {
            input.reportValidity();    // -> (*)
        })
    }

    return false;
}
```

```cs
using System;
...

public partial class User : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...checkuser
        Session["pagename"] = "User";
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetUser()
    {}

    protected void ValidationCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidationData result = new ValidationData();
        Errors errors = new Errors();
        errors.Name = true;
        errors.Contacts = true;

        result.UserInfo = UserDetails();

        bool showError = false;

        string userID = Request.Form["userID"] == null ? "" : Request.Form["userID"].ToString();
        ... other data from request.form

        if (checkingFoundErrors) showError = true;
        
        if (showError)
        {
            string jsFunc = string.Format("saveAlert({{ 'data': {0} }});", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None));
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myJsFn", jsFunc, true);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveUser_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected UserInfo UserDetails()
    {
        UserInfo result = new UserInfo();
        result.UserID= Request.Form["userID"] == null ?? "" : Request.Form["userID"].ToString();
        result.Name = Request.Form["name"] == null ?? "" : Request.Form["name"].ToString();
        result.Contacts = Request.Form["contacts"] == null ?? "" : Request.Form["name"].ToString();

        return result;
    }

    public struct UserInfo
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public struct Errors
    {
        public bool Name { get; set; }
        public bool Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public struct ValidationData
    {
        public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
        public Errors Errors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my js file function saveAlert() at (*), when i loop through all inputs and calls reportValidity() on all inputs, how do I make all inputs with errors to be popup with its invalid message, instead of the last input.